# Search form to search only products within specific attribute set

Tags: search, query, attribute-set

We have two product types in our Magento catalog/store, "default" and "Machine." Wondering if there's a way to set up a search page for each to only perform search in a specific attribute set.  Default search code below. Can I modify this? If so, how? If not, any recommendations to best achieve?

```
<form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">
    <div class="form-search">
        <input id="search" type="text" name="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getQueryParamName() ?>" placeholder="Search" class="input-text" maxlength="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getMaxQueryLength();?>"/>
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Search') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Search') ?></span></span></button>
        <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '<?php echo $this->__('Search') ?>');
            searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
        //]]>
        </script>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need add filter to catalogsearch results template `magento_dir/app/design/frontend/../.../catalogsearch/result.phtml`

Code:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/layer')->getProductCollection()->addFieldToFilter('addAttributeToFilter', <ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID>);
```

Comment: Where do I place that code in result.phtml? Also, how do I make two separate search templates?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?